# Prove $A\bigtriangleup C \subseteq$ (A$\bigtriangleup $B) $\cup$ (B$\bigtriangleup$ C )

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$A\bigtriangleup C \subseteq$ (A$\bigtriangleup $B) $\cup$ (B$\bigtriangleup$ C )

Comment: When you pose a question here, you should include your attempt to solve the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A\triangle B=(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)$,

$$(A\setminus B)\subset (A \setminus C)\cup ((C\setminus B)),$$

$$(B\setminus A)\subset (C\setminus A)\cup ((B\setminus C)).$$